# Mobile application backend

Tags: mobile, backend

I'm currently developing a mobile application that will fetch data from server by request (page load) or by notification received (e.g. GCM). 
Currently I'm starting to think about how to build the backend for that app.
I thought about using PHP to handle the http requests to my database (mySQL) and to return the response as JSON. As I see it there are many ways to implement such server and would like to hear to hear thoughts about my ideas for implementations:

1. create a single php page that will receive an Enum/Query, execute and send the results.

2. create a php page for every query needs to be made.

 Which of my implementations should I use? if none please suggest another. 
 Thank you.

P.S, this server will only use as a fetcher for SQL and push notifications. if you have any suggestion past experience about how to perform it (framework, language, anything that comes to mind) I'd be happy to learn.

Comment: You can use App42 backend service to avoid all these hassles. http://api.shephertz.com/tutorial/Getting-Started/

Answer (score 2):

You can use PHP REST Data services framework  https://github.com/chaturadilan/PHP-Data-Services

Answer (score 1):

I am also looking for information about how to power a web and mobile application that has to get and save data on the server.

I've been working with a PHP framework such as Yii Framework, and I know that this framework, and others, have the possibility to create a API/Web service.

APIS can be SOAP or REST, you should read about the differences of both to see wich is best for mobile. I think the main and most important one is that for SOAP, you need a Soap Client library on the device you are trying to connect, but for REST you just make a http request to the url.

I have built a SOAP API with Yii, is quite easy, and I have use it to communicate between two websites, to get and put data in the same database.

As for your question regarding to use one file or multiple files for every request, in the case of SOAP built on Yii, you have to normally define all the functions available to the API on the server side in only one file(controller) and to connect to that webservice you end up doing:

```
$client=new SoapClient("url/of/webservice);
$result=$client->methodName($param1, $param2, etc..);
```

So basically what you get is that from your client, you can run any method defined on the server side with the parameters that you wish.

Assuming that you use to work program php in the "classic way" I suggest you should start learning a framework, there are many reasons to do it but in the end, it is because the code will result more clean and stable, for example:

You shouldn't be writing manual queries (sometimes yes), but you can use the framework's models to handle data validation and storage into the database.

Here are some links:
http://www.larryullman.com/series/learning-the-yii-framework/
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.webservice
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/175/how-to-create-a-rest-api/

As I said, I am also looking to learn how to better power a mobile application, I know this can be achieved with a API, but I don't know if that is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. create a single php page that will receive an Enum/Query, execute and send the results.

I created a single PHP file named `api.php` that does exactly this, the project is named [PHP-CRUD-API](https://github.com/mevdschee/php-crud-api). It is quite popular.

It should take care of the boring part of the job and provides a sort of a framework to get started.

Talking about frameworks: you can integrate the script in Laravel, Symfony or SlimPHP to name a few.